# Powershell, retrieve columns width from a previous Format-Table -Autosize

Tags: powershell

`Format-Table -Autosize` is great but when used with `-GroupBy`, the columns width is computed group by group, not for the whole thing.

My idea was to `$tmp = $data | Format-Table -Autosize`, retrieve the computed columns width from `$tmp`, build a hash table describing the columns with their width and then `$data | Sort-Object <column> | Format-Table $hash -GroupBy <column>`

But despite many attempts to Google `Format-Table` result structure and `$tmp | Get-Member` I can not find the information I'm looking for.

Do you have any clue?

Comment: the `Format-Table` cmdlet does not produce objects - it produces formatting code wrapped around the butchered remnants of your objects. [*grin*] if you want to control the formatting, you will need to look into the formatting code in the `Format.ps1xml` files.

Comment: Why don't you pipe Format-Table output to Out-String/Out-File, select the first 2 lines and measure the width yourself?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I disagree, as my answer shows.  Although I reached a dead end looking through the properties.

Comment: @js2010 - i thot that is what i implied. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Well, I see an array of objects of different types, at least with select-object but not format-list.  But then I get strange errors trying to display the properties.

Comment: @js2010 - AH! i just realized my terms are wrong [*blush*] - the F-T stuff _does_ output objects ... but they are _formatting object_, not the expected normal objects that you get with `Select-Object`.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Ok, I pressed the up arrow on your last comment.  Does that give any points or notification whatsoever, lol?

Comment: @js2010 - nope, that is just the "helpful" flag. i think it means the comment should be preserved. there is no need for any credit ... tho i do thank you for pointing out the error in my comment. i will try to be a bit more careful with my terms going forward. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

Have fun digging.  It looks like the column widths are in there somewhere:

```
ps terminal | format-table -autosize | select *

ClassId2e4f51ef21dd47e99d3c952918aff9cd : 033ecb2bc07a4d43b5ef94ed5a35d280
pageHeaderEntry                         :
pageFooterEntry                         :
autosizeInfo                            : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.AutosizeInfo
shapeInfo                               : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.TableHeaderInfo
groupingEntry                           :

ClassId2e4f51ef21dd47e99d3c952918aff9cd : 9e210fe47d09416682b841769c78b8a3
shapeInfo                               :
groupingEntry                           :

ClassId2e4f51ef21dd47e99d3c952918aff9cd : 27c87ef9bbda4f709f6b4002fa4af63c
formatEntryInfo                         : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.TableRowEntry
outOfBand                               : False
writeStream                             : None

ClassId2e4f51ef21dd47e99d3c952918aff9cd : 4ec4f0187cb04f4cb6973460dfe252df
groupingEntry                           :

ClassId2e4f51ef21dd47e99d3c952918aff9cd : cf522b78d86c486691226b40aa69e95c
groupingEntry                           :


$a = ps terminal | format-table -AutoSize
$a | foreach gettype

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
False    False    FormatStartData                          Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.StartData
False    False    GroupStartData                           Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.StartData
False    False    FormatEntryData                          Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.PacketInfoData
False    False    GroupEndData                             Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.ControlInfoData
False    False    FormatEndData                            Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.ControlInfoData
```

Hmm...  I appear to have hit a dead end.

```
$a[0] | select -expand autosizeinfo
out-lineoutput : Unknown class Id a27f094f0eec4d64845801a4c06a32ae.
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.PowerShel\u2026Format.AutosizeInfo:PSObject) [out-lineoutput], PSArgumentException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatObjectDeserializerDeserializeInvalidClassId,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutLineOutputCommand
```